# how to center my icon when I collapse my sidebar

Tags: css

can anyone help me with how can I center my hamburger Icon on my sidebar? currently, when I decrease the sidebar width it's not centered at all. Can anyone help me how to accomplish it? I've also tried using `justify-content: center` on the main class however still not working.

```js
let btnSidebar = document.querySelector(".bx-menu")
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".nk-sidebar")
btnSidebar.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("close")
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.nk-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 270px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e5e5;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.nk-sidebar.close {
    width: 73px;
}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-hrd {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* flex: 0 0 50px; */
    /* padding: 10px; */
    width: 100%;
    gap: 10px;
    background: black;
}
.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-hrd .nk-sb-logo {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-nav {
    flex: 1;
}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-hrd .nk-sb-logo {
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.nk-sb-hr-ham {
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e5e5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
        background: red;
}

.ham {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #0057d9;
}
.nk-sb-company {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #0057d9;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nk-section {
    position: relative;
    left: 270px;
    width: calc(100% - 270px);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.nk-sidebar.close .nk-sb-company {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nk-sidebar.close ~ .nk-section {
    left: 73px;
    width: calc(100% - 73px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../materials/fonts/new/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../materials/css/dashboard.css">
    <script src="../materials/plugins/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="nk-sidebar">
    <div class="nk-sb-hrd">
        <div class="nk-sb-hr-ham">
            <div class="ham top"></div>
            <div class="ham mid"></div>
            <div class="ham bot"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nk-sb-company">Zybm Business Applications</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nk-sb-nav">

    </div>

    <div class="nk-sb-footer">
asdasd
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nk-section">
    <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../materials/js/dashboard.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that

```html
<div style="
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
">...CONTENT...</div>
```

I edited your code also.

```js
let btnSidebar = document.querySelector(".bx-menu")
let sidebar = document.querySelector(".nk-sidebar")
btnSidebar.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("close")
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.nk-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 270px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e5e5;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.nk-sidebar.close {
    width: 73px;
}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-hrd {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* flex: 0 0 50px; */
    /* padding: 10px; */
    width: 100%;
    gap: 10px;
    background: black;
}
.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-hrd .nk-sb-logo {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-nav {
    flex: 1;
}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.nk-sidebar .nk-sb-hrd .nk-sb-logo {
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.nk-sb-hr-ham {
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e5e5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
        background: red;
}

.ham {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #0057d9;
}
.nk-sb-company {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #0057d9;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nk-section {
    position: relative;
    left: 270px;
    width: calc(100% - 270px);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
    transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.nk-sidebar.close .nk-sb-company {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nk-sidebar.close ~ .nk-section {
    left: 73px;
    width: calc(100% - 73px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../materials/fonts/new/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../materials/css/dashboard.css">
    <script src="../materials/plugins/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="nk-sidebar">
    <div class="nk-sb-hrd">
        <div class="nk-sb-hr-ham">
            <div class="ham top"></div>
            <div class="ham mid"></div>
            <div class="ham bot"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nk-sb-company">Zybm Business Applications</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nk-sb-nav">

    </div>

    <div class="nk-sb-footer">
asdasd
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nk-section">
    <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-around;"><i class="bx bx-menu"></i></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../materials/js/dashboard.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT : https://codepen.io/agokselb/pen/eYrYBMP

Comment: Hi Ali thanks for that answer however I'm referring to the other hamburger menu on the sidebar content

Comment: Add display:none property to .nk-sidebar.close .nk-sb-company CSS class. 
https://codepen.io/agokselb/pen/eYrYBMP